# "Detect when file is changed outside the environment" Visual Studio 2015 not working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

We have some files on a network share. If someone opens and edits a file with Visual Studio and saves it, I don't get prompted that it got changed. If it gets changed by any other editor, it works fine: I get a notification.

Is there something special about how Visual Studio is saving files, making other instances not detect the change?

Also, if I just open two instances of Visual Studio locally and do a change in one, the other detects change properly. Issue happens only when someone else on the network edits a file with Visual Studio.

Thanks!

Comment: If you have several people (or even one, really) working on a project, you really need some sort of *version control system*.

Comment: Appreciate your input, we do use TFS, but for this case we are working over network as a temporary solution. I am interested to know why Visual Studio feature is not working as intended. Thanks!